# GDAL wheel 3.1.3 not supported on this platform (python 3.8.6 64-bit) Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, gdal

For python 3.8.6 (64-bit) on Windows 10, I tried to install GDAL version 3.1.3. I downloaded the following wheel: `GDAL-3.1.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

Unfortunately, I get the following error message: `GDAL-3.1.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`.

I have also tried other versions including the 32-bit and mismatched python wheels for older python versions, but to no avail. Also updated `pip` but this did not help either. Also, Using the osgeo4w or Anaconda GDAL versions is not an option for me.

Could you please help me figuring out how to install GDAL?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. Only had to downgrade `pip` to 19.* instead of 20.*